# ERROR : Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Hero[]'

Tags: angular

When I try to `"ng build --prod"`, my app shows this error :

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.html(1,7): Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Hero[]'.

But I don't have any problem with `"nodemon"` & `"ng serve"` & `"ng build"`

I only have problem with `"ng build --prod"`.

**`app.component.html`**

```
<router-outlet>
    {{ heroes?.title }}
</router-outlet>
```

**`app.component.ts`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core"
import { Hero, ConfigService } from "src/app/services/config/config.service"

@Component({
    selector: "app-root",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class GoldHomeContentComponent implements OnInit {
    heroes: Hero[]
    error: any

    constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

    getHeroes(): void {
        this.configService.getHeroes().subscribe(
            heroes => (this.heroes = heroes) ,
            error => (this.error = error)
        )
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getHeroes()
    }
}
```

**`config.service.ts`**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"
import { HttpClient , HttpHeaders  } from "@angular/common/http"
import { Observable } from "rxjs"

export interface Hero {
    title: string
}

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    })
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class ConfigService {
    heroesUrl = "/assets/data/config.json"

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
        return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl, httpOptions)
    }
}
```

**`assets/data/config.json`**

```
{
    "title": "John Doe"
}
```

**[UPDATE]**
change getHeroes() in app.component.ts

```
getHeroes(): void {
    this.configService.getHeroes().subscribe((data:any)=>{
        this.heroes = [data]
        // console.log(this.heroes = [data])
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the code, heroes looks like an array, you need to have **[`ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)** to iterate over the elements

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
   {{ hero?.title }}
</li>
```

Also change your config.json as

```
[{
    "title": "John Doe"
}]
```

If you just want to bind object, change the code as,

```
heroes: Hero;
```

rest should work fine

Comment: thanks for your replay , now i have another problem : ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: ok thanks man, i'ts worked perfectly. but what if our data.json is not [{}] ?

Comment: it means array.

Comment: yes i know that , i tried external API file with json type , but that data is not an array , it's like : {"title":"test" , .....}. i got error again ( when i tried to get an object )

Comment: oh then do this this.heroes = [heroes]